# how can i prove this linear Algebra problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations

[problem picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKrOE.png)

please help me, thank you.

Comment: Please, show the ideas you have to solve this problem...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  For part 1, use the definitions of linearly dependent and linear transformations

Comment: For the first part think about the meaning of being dependent for two vectors ($v$ and $u$ are l.d. if $v=\alpha u$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$), then use the properties of the linear functions to show the dependence of the images of the vectors.

Comment: Hello, welcome to MSE. Please type your question instead of posting a picture. To typeset math formulas, use MathJax (a tutorial can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I think I realize how to do with it. thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

**Part 1.**

We have that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly dependent.  This means, there are $c_1,c_2$, not both zero so that $$c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 = 0.$$

$T$ is linear.  $$0=T(c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2) = c_1 T(v_1) + c_2 T(v_2).$$

So $T(v_1)$ and $T(v_2)$ are linearly dependent.

**Part 2.**

False.  Any counterexample will do.  Let $v_1=(1,0)^T$, $v_2=(0,1)^T$ and let $T$ be represented by the matrix $A=\pmatrix{1 &0\\1&0}.$  Then $Av_1=(1,1)^T$ and $Av_2=(0,0)^T$, linearly dependent.  There are many examples.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I learned it. Thank you.

Comment: You are very welcome.